# Hide static strings in compiled golang executable

Tags: go

I have somethind like this in code

```
var myString = "test string"
```

I compile it and run

```
strings myexecutable | grep "test string"
```

And I see it in output. Is there some way to hide clear text strings in executable in golang? Separate file is not an option.

It's protection not from qualified hackers, but against simple users who can open executable in notepad and find encryption key.

Comment: Would you be happy with something like `var myString = string([]byte{0x74, 0x65, 0x73, 0x74, 
 0x20, 0x73, 0x74, 0x72, 0x69, 0x6e,  0x67})"`?  Or do you need the source to still be readable?

Comment: Ok, this might help, but may be there is a better solution?

Comment: You can't store sensitive data in plaintext in your binary. If it's there, someone will find it - saying it protects you from "casual" users is ridiculous.

Comment: Better in what sense?

Comment: Indeed. Anybody sophisticated and interested enough to run 'grep' on your file, is also fully capable of reading a hex dump, or any other level of reverse-engineering.

Answer (score 1):

Writing the text as a series of hex bytes won't help you -- the string will still appear as-is in the binary.

One solution is to scramble it, rot-13 maybe, or XOR all the bytes with some value, or even XOR the values with a random number generator that's initialized with a known seed value. At run-time, you will have to regenerate the string you want from the "messed-up" version.

A second issue: that variable probably has an interesting name which appears in the symbol table of the executable, so maybe pick a "dull" name for the encoded string. Maybe even bury the encoded string within a longer string.

As everyone else has noted - someone will find a way to undo your efforts and find the string no matter what you do, but maybe these ideas will help you.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

C++ solution if you ported over from golang

Here is what I currently use it has hacks to support sprintf functions which spilled plain-text in compiled binary file. You could now use w_sprintf_s instead of sprintf, like so

```
char test[256] = { 0 };
w_sprintf_s(test, 256, XorStr("test test :D %d %+d\n"), 1, 1337);
```

or use it like this to print stuff on screen for example

```
w_printf(XorStr("test I print this and can't see me inside .dll or .exe"));
```

works on variables, if you have a custom printf() you could use that as well..

```
char szGuid[255] = { 0 };
//generate serial code removed.
char finalSerial[512] = { 0 };
XorCompileTime::w_sprintf(finalSerial, XorStr("serial information=%s"), szGuid);
myprintf(XorStr("Your Hardware ID: %s\n"), szGuid);
```

May add support for wchar_t wide strings like arkan did.. but I have no use for them right now as I don't write anything in symbols / unicode.

Here is a file just rename the code below to a `XorString.h` file and include it in your project simple as that

```
#pragma once
#include <string>
#include <array>
#include <cstdarg>

#define BEGIN_NAMESPACE( x ) namespace x {
#define END_NAMESPACE }

BEGIN_NAMESPACE(XorCompileTime)

constexpr auto time = __TIME__;
constexpr auto seed = static_cast< int >(time[7]) + static_cast< int >(time[6]) * 10 + static_cast< int >(time[4]) * 60 + static_cast< int >(time[3]) * 600 + static_cast< int >(time[1]) * 3600 + static_cast< int >(time[0]) * 36000;

// 1988, Stephen Park and Keith Miller
// "Random Number Generators: Good Ones Are Hard To Find", considered as "minimal standard"
// Park-Miller 31 bit pseudo-random number generator, implemented with G. Carta's optimisation:
// with 32-bit math and without division

template < int N >
struct RandomGenerator
{
private:
    static constexpr unsigned a = 16807; // 7^5
    static constexpr unsigned m = 2147483647; // 2^31 - 1

    static constexpr unsigned s = RandomGenerator< N - 1 >::value;
    static constexpr unsigned lo = a * (s & 0xFFFF); // Multiply lower 16 bits by 16807
    static constexpr unsigned hi = a * (s >> 16); // Multiply higher 16 bits by 16807
    static constexpr unsigned lo2 = lo + ((hi & 0x7FFF) << 16); // Combine lower 15 bits of hi with lo's upper bits
    static constexpr unsigned hi2 = hi >> 15; // Discard lower 15 bits of hi
    static constexpr unsigned lo3 = lo2 + hi;

public:
    static constexpr unsigned max = m;
    static constexpr unsigned value = lo3 > m ? lo3 - m : lo3;
};

template <>
struct RandomGenerator< 0 >
{
    static constexpr unsigned value = seed;
};

template < int N, int M >
struct RandomInt
{
    static constexpr auto value = RandomGenerator< N + 1 >::value % M;
};

template < int N >
struct RandomChar
{
    static const char value = static_cast< char >(1 + RandomInt< N, 0x7F - 1 >::value);
};

template < size_t N, int K >
struct XorString
{
private:
    const char _key;
    std::array< char, N + 1 > _encrypted;

    constexpr char enc(char c) const
    {
        return c ^ _key;
    }

    char dec(char c) const
    {
        return c ^ _key;
    }

public:
    template < size_t... Is >
    constexpr __forceinline XorString(const char* str, std::index_sequence< Is... >) : _key(RandomChar< K >::value), _encrypted{ enc(str[Is])... }
    {
    }

    __forceinline decltype(auto) decrypt(void)
    {
        for (size_t i = 0; i < N; ++i) {
            _encrypted[i] = dec(_encrypted[i]);
        }
        _encrypted[N] = '\0';
        return _encrypted.data();
    }
};

//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
//-- Note: XorStr will __NOT__ work directly with functions like printf.
//         To work with them you need a wrapper function that takes a const char*
//         as parameter and passes it to printf and alike.
//
//         The Microsoft Compiler/Linker is not working correctly with variadic 
//         templates!
//  
//         Use the functions below or use std::cout (and similar)!
//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

static auto w_printf = [](const char* fmt, ...) {
    va_list args;
    va_start(args, fmt);
    vprintf_s(fmt, args);
    va_end(args);
};

static auto w_printf_s = [](const char* fmt, ...) {
    va_list args;
    va_start(args, fmt);
    vprintf_s(fmt, args);
    va_end(args);
};

static auto w_sprintf = [](char* buf, const char* fmt, ...) {
    va_list args;
    va_start(args, fmt);
    vsprintf(buf, fmt, args);
    va_end(args);
};

static auto w_sprintf_s = [](char* buf, size_t buf_size, const char* fmt, ...) {
    va_list args;
    va_start(args, fmt);
    vsprintf_s(buf, buf_size, fmt, args);
    va_end(args);
};

#define XorStr( s ) ( XorCompileTime::XorString< sizeof( s ) - 1, __COUNTER__ >( s, std::make_index_sequence< sizeof( s ) - 1>() ).decrypt() )

END_NAMESPACE
```

> Blockquote